# Eclipse with JDK1.6 on OSX 10.10.1 not able to show Javadoc

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc, java-6

When working in Eclipse (Luna/Kepler) with JDK1.6 installed on Mac OSX 10.10.1 Eclipse is not able to display the Javadoc of any system java components (e.g. `java.lang.String`). When trying so the following error happens:

```
Unknown javadoc format for String {key=Ljava/lang/String;} [in String.class [in java.lang [in /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar]]]
```

My session data is:

```
eclipse.buildId=4.4.1.M20140925-0400
java.version=1.6.0_65
java.vendor=Apple Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=de_DE
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -keyring /Users/ihle/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -keyring /Users/ihle/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
```

I've tried to set the correct JDK (under "installed JRE's") in Eclipse's preferences, without any success. Strange is when I open the preferences there is no installed JRE listed, but when clicking "search..." the previously selected JRE is listed and ticked.

Nevertheless Eclipse still can open the online javadoc location of all java classes.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by linking a manually downloaded javadoc archive to every lib in the installed JRE.